# Update a specific component using redux

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

Im using redux, for dispatching an expand event from a component to an another.

These components are used inside a table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let business of businesses">
          <app-business-header-cell [business]="business"></app-business-header-cell>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

My header component:

```
export class BusinessHeaderCellComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  business: Business;

  @select() columnState$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClickExpand(){
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'EXPAND', id: this.business.id });
  }

  onClickCollapse(){
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'COLLAPSE', id: this.business.id });
  }

}
```

The dispatch and the state update are working fine.

My problem is that when i dispatch my action EXPAND, it's intercepted by all the other header component. Is there a way to make a distinction for which component should be updated?

Comment: After some digging, i found this article: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/05/19/redux-reducer-arrays.html which explain how to go from using a single counter to multi-counter but can't find a good example using angular 2.

Comment: Split your state accordingly, it's always good to (before working with redux) architect a state for your app/redux.

Comment: My state is really simple. The problem is that it's being used by a generic component. I can't really what you mean about "architect a state".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution i've come up with:

```
export class BusinessHeaderCellComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  business: Business;

  @select() columnState$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // ADDED THIS
    this.columnState$.subscribe(state => {
      if(this.business.id == state.id) this.isExpanded = state.isExpanded;
    });
  }

  onClickExpand(){
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'EXPAND', id: this.business.id });
  }

  onClickCollapse(){
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'COLLAPSE', id: this.business.id });
  }

}
```